# Select Max revenue by date and client

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following is sample data from my table:

```
Rev       Date          Client
1890      2015-11-20    xyz
1536.28   2017-10-27    AAA
934.84    2017-10-27    AAA
919.592   2017-03-22    AAA 
760.985   2014-11-25    xyz
```

I need to select the day with the highest revenue for each client.

I have the following query but it selects the max revenue for each day by client rather than just the day with the highest rev per client

```
SELECT TOP 1 max(rev)/1000 AS Rev, date, client FROM table1 GROUP BY date, client
```

Comment: If you don't want it to group by client, then remove it from group by.  If you need client info, you have to use inner query to get the max.

Comment: I assume TD is Date.  If you `group by TD, client` then those are the groups you will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common question. I presume that Rev is already totaled per day and we're just picking out the highest row. If there are ties you could use `dense_rank()` instead.

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Client order by Rev desc) as rn
    from table1
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the the **WITH TIES** clause in concert with **Row_Number()**

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Client Order By Rev Desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    Rev money
    , [Date] date
    , Client nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
    (1890, '2015-11-20', 'xyz')
    ,(1536.28, '2017-10-27', 'AAA')
    ,(934.84, '2017-10-27', 'AAA')
    ,(919.592, '2017-03-22', 'AAA') 
    ,(760.985, '2014-11-25', 'xyz')
```

Query:

```
SELECT Client
    , t.[Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT Client
        , [Date]
        , SUM(Rev) AS [TotalRev]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY SUM(Rev) DESC) AS RN
    FROM @data
    GROUP BY Client, [Date]
) AS t
WHERE t.RN = 1
```

Results:

```
Client    Date
====================
AAA       2017-10-27
xyz       2015-11-20
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding michaelg's question is per day the highest revenue transactions, so:

```
 select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [date] order by Rev desc) as rn
    from ##table1
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If you want total amount of your client, you have group all rev into subquery.

Please try your script in my T-SQL Code playground https://sqleditor.net/q/B19r72H_f

Answer (score -1):

I would use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) for this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.*
FROM table1 t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM table1
             WHERE Client = t.Client
             ORDER BY Rev DESC) ca
```

It's cleaner if you already have a `Client` table that has unique ids.

```
SELECT ca.Rev, ca.Date, c.Client
FROM Client c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Rev, Date
             FROM table1
             WHERE Client = c.Client
             ORDER BY Rev DESC) ca
```